# Using pytables and pandas with Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, pandas, pytables

Does anyone know of a good way to use pytables with the Django as a datastore (mainly reading data)? I am hoping to store large amounts of log data using pytables and then access it in my django app (via pandas - the pandas/pytables interplay is described by one of the comments).

I believe that the Django has an MVC architecture where the models wrap an RDS. Is it possible for to wrap a PyTable instead of an RDS in the model? Or would I need to do this in the controller (which I am guessing would break the MVC)?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: This is pretty vague/non constructive, I think you're going to be more specific, interesting question though :)

Comment: see pandas support for HDF5 via Pytables: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#hdf5-pytables; after reading pls come back with questions

Comment: Thanks both! Just edit q to make a little clearer.